# AWS Cloudformation communicating using internal IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a web application using AWS Cloudformation. This particular app will have 3 instances (Web server, App server, RDS database). I want these instances to be able to talk to each other. For example, the Web server should talk to App server, and the App server should talk to RDS database.

I can't understand how to configure the servers so that they know each other's IP address. I figure there are 3 ways to do this - but I'm not sure which of these is realistically possible or feasible:

1. I can assign a fixed private IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.2 and so on) during stack creation - this way I know beforehand the IP address of each instance
2. I can wait for AWS Cloudformation to return the IP addresses of the created instances and manually tweak my code to use these IP addresses to communicate using these IPs
3. I can somehow get the IP address of the created instance during the stack creation process and store it as a parameter in the next instance I create (not sure if Cloudformation allows this?)

Which is the best way to set this up? Also, please share a little bit of detail around how I can do this in Cloudformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to place your Web server and App server behind an ELB (load balancer). This way, your web server will communicate with the app server using the ELB's URL (not the app server's IP). The app server can communicate with the RDS instance via the RDS instance's endpoint (which is again an URL).

Let's suppose you separate your infrastructure into 3 CloudFormation stacks: the RDS database, the app server and the web server. The RDS stack will expose the RDS instance's through the CloudFormation Outputs feature. This endpoint will in turn be used as an CloudFormation Parameter to the App server stack. You can insert the RDS endpoint in the App server LauchConfiguration's UserData field, so that on startup, your App server will know the RDS instance's endpoint. Finally, your App server stack will expose the App server's ELB endpoint (again using the CloudFormation outputs feature). Using the same recipe, the URL of your App server's ELB will be injected and used by your Web server stack.

As a side note, it is also a good idea to oversee your services (web server, app server) using an Autoscaling group. It is very probable that your instances will be terminated by factors out of you control. In that case, you would want the Autoscaling group to start a fresh new instance and place it behind your ELB.

Comment: Thanks @spg.. I see what you mean here. I'm not a big fan of using public URLs for the database, but it could work for the app server. Cheers!

Comment: The URLs do not need to be public. You can keep everything private within your VPC if you want.